# Upstart doesn't log exec or exec right away

Tags: python, linux, server, upstart, system-administration

all.

So, I make an Upstart script to run my python script forever in the server. It's working, but when the service starts, the python script is not started/executed right away. It waits between a lot of minutes until hours before it starts. The delay time varies a lot.

When the scripts already start (I notice by monitoring the change on the database), it doesn't always write the execution log right away. Well, it's all kind of weird.

Is it common? How can I make it the python script to get executed right away when the upstart service was started?

This is my script:

```
#!upstart
description "THIS IS MY SCRIPT"
author      "ANONYMOUS"

start on startup
stop on shutdown
console log

script
    export HOME="/root"
    echo $$ > /var/run/myScript.pid
    exec python /myPath/myScript.py >> /var/log/myScript.log 2>&1
    set -x
end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >>/var/log/myScript.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/myScript.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopped " >> /var/log/myScript.log
end script
```

Thanks before

Comment: What do you mean by "start when compiled?"

Comment: so, the service starts, the pid is there, but python script execution is delayed a lot. can you help me?

Comment: You can check the upstart log for your job (in `/var/log/upstart/`). It will log if the job crashes, and it will log stdout and stderr to that file. Maybe your script just takes a while to get to the point of updating the database when it is run?

Comment: If I run the python script right away without upstart, it access database right away and give output right away too. Already check that log, nothing shown